# ASP.NET and Passing Variables from a Request.Querystring into a SQLdatasource SelectCommand

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been researching for days and still unable to find a resolution to what would seem a simple questions.  I have a ASP Gridview where I have a select link to allow the user to select a record for editing.  The page then links to an edit page and it passes the Record Index to the next page by using a "Response.Redirect("~/admn-VenueEdit.aspx?VenueID=" + e.CommandArgument)".  Then I am able to get that record index (Integer) by using a "QueryID = CInt(Int(Request.QueryString("VenueID")))" code in the VB page behind.  I want to then pass the QueryID index to the edit page.

Here is the code that is not working.

```
       <asp:SqlDataSource 
        ID="SqlDataSource1" 
         runat="server" 
          ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"

        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblVenue]  Where [ID] = @QueryField" >

    <SelectParameters>
       <asp:QueryStringParameter 
       Name="QueryField" 
       QueryStringField="QueryID" 
       DbType="Int32"/>
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is in the Code Behind Page

```
Private Sub SqlDataSource1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Load
        Dim QueryID As String
        QueryID = CInt(Int(Request.QueryString("VenueID")))
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
Private Sub SqlDataSource1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Load
        Dim QueryID As String
        QueryID = CInt(Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("VenueID")))>
```